# Running into infinite loop with View controller Delegation

Tags: ios, delegates

I have the following code, and have been struggling with it for quite some time. I have two view controllers, FirstView and SecondView. I pushViewController from FirstView to SecondView. In SecondView there is a UITextView where I take user's input. Then I save that input using a delegate in SecondView to FirstView's variable called text. When I run this, the code gets into an infinite loop on calling the delegate from SecondView.

FirstView.m

```
UIStoryboard *story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
SecondView *secondView = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondView"];
secondView.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];

-(void)setText:(NSString *)strData
{
NSLog(@"Entered setText delegate");
NSLog(@"Current string is %@", strData);
self.text = strData;
}
```

SecondView.h

```
@protocol SetInstructionDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)setText:(NSString *)strData;
@end

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SetInstructionDelegate> delegate;
```

SecondView.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
/****************************** Done Button framing ********************************/
UIButton *btn_bar=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
[btn_bar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[btn_bar setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn_bar addTarget:self action:@selector(doneEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *doneEdit=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn_bar];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=doneEdit;
}

-(void)doneEditing:(id) sender
{
[self.view.window endEditing: YES];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@"Current text is : %@", self.textView.text);
[[self delegate] setText:self.textView.text];
}
```

The code stays in doneEditing, and keeps printing the NSLogs repeatedly. I read quite a few links on this but cannot find a definite answer and have been struggling. I am very new to iOS and delegate methods. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use the debugger. You can see clearly how the recursion occurs if you just stop and look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've got a property called `text` and a method called `setText:`. Give that method (or that property, I don't care which) a different name. Really it should be the method; giving a method wantonly a name starting with `set...` is always potentially a very dangerous thing to do.

The reason is that setting a property called `text` is in fact nothing but a shorthand for calling a method called `setText:`. Thus, this is an infinite recursion:

```
-(void)setText:(NSString *)strData
{
self.text = strData;
}
```

That code, you see, is *exactly* the same as saying:

```
-(void)setText:(NSString *)strData
{
[self setText: strData];
}
```

Behold your infinite recursion in all its glory.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matt. And yes I will make sure about the setter method in future. That was really helpful..

Comment: It's another good reason for using Swift instead of Objective-C. In Swift, this trap doesn't exist. That is _why_ Swift is designed the way it is; its purpose is to help prevent people from falling into the typical Objective-C hidden traps.